# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable, dataset, runtime-error

This error may be common and might be present in other questions also but I have a strange case wherein I am getting this error message

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly

***I am getting this error only when i am passing the DataTable in a service but not getting the error when i put it in a DataSet.***
I have checked online for past few days but couldnt find out the mystery behind it.
I just had a simple doubt if WCF service accepts data only if it is in a container type only.

```
    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetCurrencyDetails(int CurrencyId); // No error for the service

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetCurrencyDetailsDataTable(int CurrencyId); //getting error for the same service
```

Here both of them returns the same result but one in DataSet having the DataTable and another directly DataTable.

At the client end the code is

```
        UtilityClient client= new UtilityClient("BasicHttpBinding_IUtility");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = client.GetCurrencyDetailsDataTable(CurrencyId); //error at this point
        ds =client.GetCurrencyDetails(CurrencyId); // no error here for dataset
```

I have also checked the inner exception which is mentioned but it only has the error described in Title

Here is my Error details in View Detail
[image]
I wish if i could get a solution for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Am am proceeding by using the DataSet itself for all my responses. DataTable is fetching me the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of general guidance, you may want to enable WCF Tracing and Message Logging, which will allow you to monitor/review the WCF transactions and hopefully discover additional information about the issue.

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: i have all those already and have got Traces in log file. i couldn't figure out what to do with that. I have got the message Errror report on opening. The 'TraceIdentifier' start tage on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'Tracel' Line 1, position 778. i can also find some red, yellow and black commands in the Activity when opened.